# Jupyter input, display, print execution order is chaotic

Tags: python, pandas, output, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter and my Python version is 3.5. In my `while` loop, execution order is not correct; the `input` from one iteration is shown *before* the final `print` of the previous iteration. This is my code.

```
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4]})
while(True):
    a = input("please input:\n")
    display(df.head())
    print (a)
```

The execution result is
[image: screenshot of execution]

Comment: Your code runs well and output in correct order on my jupyter. Maybe it's a problem of your development environment.

Comment: If it's a problem of your development environment,  it's hard to solve it.

Comment: Try with `del a` after `print(a)` and remove `\n`

Comment: @virtualdvid, it doen't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the behavior under Chrome 63 on OSX. I added several more consecutive `print(a)` statements and where the input field ends up is random: before them, after them, or in between. My suspicion is that each display and print call sends a request to the server but awaits its result asynchronously, so that `input` may be called again before the result from `print(a)` is ready.

It is not an elegant solution, but adding a small sleep (`time.sleep(.02)`) after `print(a)` fixes the problem for me.

Comment: Yeah,display  and print seem to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known Jupyter issue:

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3159